# replace part of href between 2 words jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is simple and I have done it before but can't make it work right now.

I need to change the name of the image in below href

```js
var href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl.com/&description='tets'&picture=http://myurl.com/img/name-1654-45654.jpg" 

$('.share, .share-2').prop('href', function () {
    $(this).replace(/(picture=).*?(&)/,'$1' + imgNew + '$2');
});
```

Comment: this will also replace the "picture="

Comment: I am getting this error $(...).replace is not a function.

Comment: It's not clear what the expected output should be or what `imgNew` is, however the URL object is probably the way to go. I answered below.

Comment: Turn `function ()` into `function (i, old)` and use `return old.replace(...)`

Comment: Doc: [$.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) You also don't have an `&` after your picture parameter, which is why your example `href` will not match the RegEx. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8s97686s/

Comment: I think i got it, thanks Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace` function is a method of `string`, so you can't call `replace` from `$(this)` because it is a jQuery object, not a string.

If you need to change the `href` attribute, just use `this.href = ...`.

**EDIT**: As you are using [jQuery.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) method you should use it as docs proposes.

```
$(".some-element").prop('some-prop', function(index, old_value){
    // do something
    return new_value;
});
```

**Snippet updated**:

```js
var new_img = "http://my.domain.com/img/my_new_image.jpg";
var regex_img = /\bpicture=[^&]*/

$('.share, .share-2').prop('href', function (index, old_href) {
    var new_href = old_href.replace(regex_img, 'picture=' + new_img);
    console.log(new_href);
    return new_href;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl.com/&description='tets'&picture=http://myurl.com/img/name-1654-45654.jpg" class="share">Test</a>
<br>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl.com/&picture=http://myurl.com/img/name-1654-45654.jpg&description='tets'" class="share-2">Test-2</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the *actual* issue, namely how to properly use `$.prop(attribute, function)`. I suggest fixing the answer accordingly. See my comments on the question.

Comment: Actually he doesn't need to use `$.prop` to do what he need. That is why I suggested to use `this.href`. His mistake was trying to use `$(this).replace`.
Don't you think the actual issue is changing the `picture` parameter in href?
I don't think it is about using `$.prop` function.

Comment: Wow, now I got it! I will fix that

Answer (score 3):

Since the `href` string is a URL, you can take advantage of the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL) object.

```js
var imgNew = 'http://example.com/img.png';
var href = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl.com/&description='tets'&picture=http://myurl.com/img/name-1654-45654.jpg";
var url = new URL(href);
url.searchParams.set('picture', imgNew);
console.log(url.href);
```

Note that not all browsers are [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams) at this time, so you can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params).

Comment: As far as I understand, this question isn't about how to replace the URL, it's about how to use jQuery's `$(...).prop(attribute, function)`.

Comment: It's hard to know which part is failing without the complete code.

Comment: It would be nice to add the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL#Browser_compatibility) to the answer.

Comment: Couldnt make it work, guess coz of compatibility issues, but thanks a lot

Comment: @fernandosavio Good idea. I updated with several hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?
 u=http://myurl.com/&description='tets'&picture=http://myurl.com/img/name-
 1654-45654.jpg"
 href.split('/')
 ["https:", "", "www.facebook.com", "sharer", "sharer.php?u=http:", "", 
 "myurl.com", "&description='tets'&picture=http:", "", "myurl.com", "img", 
 "name-1654-45654.jpg"]
  href.split('/').length
 12
 href.split('/')[11]
"name-1654-45654.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to the following one.

```
  href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myurl.com/&description='tets'&picture=http://myurl.com/img/name-1654-45654.jpg" 

    $('.share, .share-2').prop('href', function () {
        $(this).replace(/\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, '/newpicturename'));
       });
```

The last slash and following words will be replaced by the new picture name.

An example

```js
var str = "http://one/two/three/four";
console.log(str.replace(/\/(?=[^\/]*$)/, '/newpicturename'));
```